# Get all member even inherited one from ClassDeclarationSyntax using ISyntaxReceiver

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a source generator but i need to get all methods of a class even inherited ones, ClassDeclarationSyntax has a Members list that has all methods that the class has but unfortunately that list doesn't include the inherited ones.

Below there is the current code that I have done for context.

```
public class ControllerSyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> Candidates { get; set; }
    
    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
        if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
        {
            var name = classDeclaration.Identifier.ValueText;
            if (name.EndsWith("Controller"))
            {
                Candidates.Add(classDeclaration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```